# Newly posted ajax content can't be deleted directly but it can after refreshing the page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a comment system where an user can post an comment. This posting of a comment is an ajax call:

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit-comment").click(function() {

        var text = $(".txtinput").val();
        var itemid = "<?=$id?>";
        var userid = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>";
        var dataString = 'text=' + text + '&userid=' + userid + '&itemid=' + itemid;

        if (text == '') {
            $('#content_error1').fadeIn(250);
            $('#content_error1').delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
        } else {    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/comments.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#messages').prepend($(html).hide().fadeIn(1000));
                    $('.txtinput').val('');    
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
```

giving this html output:

```
<div class="com_loaded" id="id<?=$comment_id?>">
   <div id="com_loaded_height"></div>
   <div id="com_loaded_userpic"><a onClick="parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();" target="_parent" href="profile.php?id=<?=$row['user_id']?>"
      class="tooltip"><img src="<?=$row['user_pic']?>" class="img_poster" /><span><?=$row['user_name']?></span></a>
   </div>
   <div id="com_loaded_content">
      <div id="com_loaded_poster"><a onClick="parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();" target="_parent" href="profile.php?id=<?=$row['user_id']?>"><?=$row['user_name']?></a>
      </div>
      <div id="com_loaded_text">
         <?=$row[ 'comment_text']?>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="com_loaded_divide"></div>
   <div class="del_com"><span class="imgswap_del" att="<?=$comment_id?>"><img src="img/popup/close-small.png" alt="Delete comment"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now you can delete a comment using this ajax call:

```
$(function() {
    $(".imgswap_del").click(function() {

        var comment_id = $(this).attr('att');
        var dataString = 'comment_id=' + comment_id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/delete_comment.php",
            data: dataString,
        }).done(function(result) {
            myresult7(result);
        });

        return false;
    });
});​
```

I want to give the user the option to directly delete the comment after posting. This isn't working. But the strange part is, that when I refresh the page the function is working. How can I make this work directly after posting a comment with an ajax call? I don't want to refresh the page first!

Answer (score 4):

You need to either bind the delete click event using event delegation, or rebind it with every new comment. I suggest event delegation.

```
$(document).on("click",".imgswap_del",function() {...
```

The above would work, but it would be better to use a closer element, such as

```
$("#messages").on("click",".imgswap_del",function() {...
```

Comment: if you read his code, it gives you the closest parent element. Bind it to `$('#messages')`